# SSL Socket Help - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, ssl-certificate, bouncycastle

I am having a problem establishing a Client-Server Socket connection using SSL Sockets. I am still in the learning process of SSL encryption and dealing with certificates and keystores. I have a client and server application that are supposed to connect to one another as follows:

**SERVER** - SSLReverseEchoer.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class SSLReverseEchoer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     String ksName = "sslkeystore.jks";
     String keystorePass = "sslkeystorepassword";
     char ksPass[] = keystorePass.toCharArray();

     int sslPort = 9099; 

     Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

     File file = new File(ksName);
     String absPath = file.getAbsolutePath(); 

     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", absPath); 
     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "sslkeystorepassword");

     try {

         //Get keystore w/ password
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(ksName), ksPass);

        //Trust Manager
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ks);

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        kmf.init(ks, ksPass);

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

        SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = sc.getServerSocketFactory();
        SSLServerSocket s = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(sslPort);
        printServerSocketInfo(s);

        //WAIT FOR CONNECTION TODO ADD THREAD for NIO
        SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) s.accept();
        printSocketInfo(c);

        BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
           c.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
           c.getInputStream()));

        String m = "Welcome to SSL Reverse Echo Server."+
           " Please type in some words.";
        w.write(m,0,m.length());
        w.newLine();
        w.flush();
        while ((m=r.readLine())!= null) {
           if (m.equals(".")) break;
           char[] a = m.toCharArray();
           int n = a.length;
           for (int i=0; i<n/2; i++) {
              char t = a[i];
              a[i] = a[n-1-i];
              a[n-i-1] = t;
           }
           w.write(a,0,n);
           w.newLine();
           w.flush();
        }
        w.close();
        r.close();
        c.close();
        s.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
  private static void printSocketInfo(SSLSocket s) {
     System.out.println("Socket class: "+s.getClass());
     System.out.println("   Remote address = "
        +s.getInetAddress().toString());
     System.out.println("   Remote port = "+s.getPort());
     System.out.println("   Local socket address = "
        +s.getLocalSocketAddress().toString());
     System.out.println("   Local address = "
        +s.getLocalAddress().toString());
     System.out.println("   Local port = "+s.getLocalPort());
     System.out.println("   Need client authentication = "
        +s.getNeedClientAuth());
     SSLSession ss = s.getSession();
     System.out.println("   Cipher suite = "+ss.getCipherSuite());
     System.out.println("   Protocol = "+ss.getProtocol());
  }
  private static void printServerSocketInfo(SSLServerSocket s) {
     System.out.println("Server socket class: "+s.getClass());
     System.out.println("   Socket address = "
        +s.getInetAddress().toString());
     System.out.println("   Socket port = "
        +s.getLocalPort());
     System.out.println("   Need client authentication = "
        +s.getNeedClientAuth());
     System.out.println("   Want client authentication = "
        +s.getWantClientAuth());
     System.out.println("   Use client mode = "
        +s.getUseClientMode());
  } 
}
```

**CLIENT** - SSLSocketClient.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;

public class SSLSocketClient {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

     int sslPort = 9099; 

     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     PrintStream out = System.out;

     SSLSocketFactory f = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

     try {
        SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) f.createSocket("localhost", sslPort);
        printSocketInfo(c);
        c.startHandshake();

        BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(c.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));

        String m = null;
        while ((m=r.readLine())!= null) {
           out.println(m);
           m = in.readLine();
           w.write(m,0,m.length());
           w.newLine();
           w.flush();
        }
        w.close();
        r.close();
        c.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
  private static void printSocketInfo(SSLSocket s) {
     System.out.println("Socket class: "+s.getClass());
     System.out.println("   Remote address = "
        +s.getInetAddress().toString());
     System.out.println("   Remote port = "+s.getPort());
     System.out.println("   Local socket address = "
        +s.getLocalSocketAddress().toString());
     System.out.println("   Local address = "
        +s.getLocalAddress().toString());
     System.out.println("   Local port = "+s.getLocalPort());
     System.out.println("   Need client authentication = "
        +s.getNeedClientAuth());
     SSLSession ss = s.getSession();
     System.out.println("   Cipher suite = "+ss.getCipherSuite());
     System.out.println("   Protocol = "+ss.getProtocol());
  }
}
```

I execute the **SERVER** and it begins listening on the specified port, but when the **CLIENT** is executed I get the following stacktraces.

**SERVER OUTPUT**

```
Server socket class: class sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl
   Socket address = 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
   Socket port = 9099
   Need client authentication = false
   Want client authentication = false
   Use client mode = false
Socket class: class sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl
   Remote address = /127.0.0.1
   Remote port = 62145
   Local socket address = /127.0.0.1:9099
   Local address = /127.0.0.1
   Local port = 9099
   Need client authentication = false
   Cipher suite = SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL
   Protocol = NONE
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1541)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1553)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:71)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
    at com.example.SSLReverseEchoer.main(SSLReverseEchoer.java:60)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.getSession(SSLSocketImpl.java:2267)
    at com.example.SSLReverseEchoer.printSocketInfo(SSLReverseEchoer.java:94)
    at com.example.SSLReverseEchoer.main(SSLReverseEchoer.java:49)
```

**CLIENT OUTPUT**

```
Socket class: class sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl
   Remote address = localhost/127.0.0.1
   Remote port = 9099
   Local socket address = /127.0.0.1:62145
   Local address = /127.0.0.1
   Local port = 62145
   Need client authentication = false
   Cipher suite = SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL
   Protocol = NONE
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1541)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1553)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1399)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at com.example.SSLSocketClient.main(SSLSocketClient.java:23)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.getSession(SSLSocketImpl.java:2267)
    at com.example.SSLSocketClient.printSocketInfo(SSLSocketClient.java:55)
    at com.example.SSLSocketClient.main(SSLSocketClient.java:22)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 15 more
```

I used keystore to generate **sslkeystore.jks** and **X509_certificate.cer** with the following parameters:

**Generate sslkeystore.jks**

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias sslsocket -keystore sslkeystore.jks -storepass sslkeystorepassword -validity 365 -keysize 2048
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  Gandalf
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  Wizardry
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:  Arnock  
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]:  Minas Tirith
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:  Gondor
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:  GD
Is CN=Gandalf, OU=Wizardry, O=Arnock, L=Minas Tirith, ST=Gondor, C=GD correct?
  [no]:  yes

Enter key password for <sslsocket>
    (RETURN if same as keystore password):
```

**Export certificate.cer**

```
keytool -export -alias sslsocket -keystore sslkeystore.jks -rfc -file X509_certificate.cer
Enter keystore password:  
Certificate stored in file <X509_certificate.cer>
```

Any suggestions on what is going wrong here?

What I am trying to achieve here is asymmetric encryption on a socket with public and private keys. Doesn't the *.jks hold the public key and the *.cer hold the private key? If this is the case do I need something additional in the client to use the private key or is it given to the client during the handshake?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

**You've got it backwards.** [As the Wikipedia article begins:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)

> **Public-key cryptography**, or **asymmetric cryptography**, is any cryptographic system that uses pairs of keys: *public keys* that may be disseminated widely [which are mathematically] paired with *private keys* which are known only to the owner.

An SSL/TLS server **keeps its private key private; it is the public key that is given out** to others, specifically clients. But as wp also says

> The binding between a public key and its "owner" must be correct, or else the algorithm may function perfectly and yet be entirely insecure in practice. [...] Associating a public key with its owner is typically done by protocols implementing a public key infrastructure – these allow the validity of the association to be formally verified by reference to a trusted third party in the form of either a hierarchical certificate authority (e.g., X.509) [...]

Although PKC in general has other options, SSL/TLS normally (and in Java always) uses X.509 certificates. A **certificate** for a party, here the server, **contains the publickey** of that party, the identity of that party (for SSL/TLS server, normally the DNS name or sometimes multiple names of the server), and some other information you can ignore, **normally signed by a [Certificate Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority)**.

Normally, reliers (clients) already have installed copies of the 'root' certs of well-known CAs like Verisign, GoDaddy, etc., and perhaps more local CAs like your employer or a state government, and the server simply sends its own certficate, plus any needed 'chain' or intermediate cert(s) provided by the CA, in the SSL/TLS handshake; the client can verify the cert using its pre-installed copy of the root. (For Java client, see below.)

However, if you don't bother to or aren't qualified to get a certificate from a real CA, the SSL/TLS protocol can **instead** use a certificate the server signs itself, called a **self-signed certificate**. In this case since the client has no *a priori* way of knowing that a particular cert is the correct one for the server and not a fake one created by an impostor, you need to put the server's self-signed cert in the client's truststore. In general you need to securely copy the cert from the server to the client(s), but since you are apparently testing on a single host that problem is greatly simplified.

Concretely in Java:

- `keytool -genkeypair`, or its obsolete synonym `-genkey`, creates a keypair in a file, by default a JKS file, with a self-signed (default) certificate
- `keytool -exportcert` (or `-export`) copies the certificate (containing the publickey and name) to a file, which here you named `X509_certficate.cer`. Since you didn't get a real CA cert, this is the self-signed cert and you need to put it in the truststore of the/each client.

There are three ways of getting a cert into a Java client's truststore:

- explicit 1: put the cert in a keystore file, usually JKS, using `keytool -importcert`, read that keystore into memory, and use it to initalize a `TrustManager` then an `SSLContext` then an `SSLSocketFactory`. This is similar to your server code except without the `KeyManager` part and you use `SSLSocket` classes instead of `SSLServerSocket` classes.
- explicit 2: read (just) the cert from a file using `CertificateFactory` of type `X.509`, create a keystore in memory (no keystore file) and put the cert in it, and then proceed as in explicit 1.
  If you need multiple trusted certs, you can read each one and put them all in memory, but this quickly becomes more work than reading a single keystore file containing all of them.
- middle: put the cert in a keystore file, and set system properties `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `...trustStorePassword` (and `...trustStoreType` if not the default JKS, or in Java8 also PKCS12) to point to it, before the first creation of an SSL socket. You can set system properties by calling `System.setProperty`, or using the flag `-Dname=value` on the command line when starting `java`.
- implicit: add the cert to the file used by default, which is `JREHOME/lib/security/cacerts` (or `jssecacerts` if that exists, but by default it doesn't) and is installed to contain about a hundred well-known CAs. This affects all programs using that JRE unless they set their own truststores using the options above, which may or may not be an issue depending on what else you or anyone else runs (in Java) on this system.

Finally, **CommonName** in an SSL/TLS server certificate, which is the field actually set when `keytool` prompts for `first and last name` (notice `CN=Gandalf` in the readback, CN means CommonName), **should be the hostname** of the server, or more exactly the name **used by client(s)** to connect *to* the server (which in your example was apparently `localhost`). Alternatively, especially with real-CA certs, an extension named SubjectAlternativeName (abbreviated SAN) can be used for this, but doing SAN with `keytool` is rather clumsy.

The basic `SSLSocket` logic does NOT (currently) verify hostname, but most other clients like web browsers (and even `HttpsURLConnection` in Java) do verify this, and unless your server can be connected as `Gandalf` (without any domain qualification) those clients will refuse to connect to your server using the cert even though the cert itself is 'valid'.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I realize now that my wording of the public/private relationship was off. I am try and add the self-signed cert to the clients' truststore. I do have a follow up question,

Comment: Is it common practice for a java client to have a cert bundled with the application? and if using a self signed cert do you have to match the CommonName to the hostname of the server? Will authentication errors occur if this is different?

Comment: (1) it is certainly possible to bundle the cert for a peer with a Java app; the jar format makes that easy to manage and use. I'm not sure how common it is. If the jar is signed that handles the 'distribute securely' issue, although it goes to the next turtle: what key&cert do you sign with? Also to change/update the cert you must create and distribute a new version of the app; if your app is updated frequently for other reasons this is easy to add but otherwise maybe less so.

Comment: (2) as I said _most_ connections, including all browsers and `HttpsURLConnection` in Java, do check that CN (or SAN if used) in the cert matches the hostname of the server and fail if not, but plain `SSLSocket` as in your posted code does not. This hostname check is the same for a self-signed cert and a real-CA cert, although of course you have more control over the hostname(s) in a self-signed cert.